# multiple array assigning to pointer to pointer in C

Tags: c

I have two arrays

```
int x[]={1,2,3,4};
int y[]={5,6,7};
```

I like to create two dimensional array. assign x and y. Can I do something like this

```
int x[]={1,2,3,4};
int y[]={5,6,7};
int *k=x;
int *l=y;
int **m={k,l};
printf("%d\n",m[0][0]);
```

but at `printf` when 1 is get accessed throws segFault

What I am doing wrong

Comment: I'm surprised that the compiler swallowed `int **m={k,l};`. Your code should work if you change that line to `int *m[2]={k,l};`, making `m` an array and not a pointer; this could (and should, for robustness) be changed to `int *m[]={k,l};`. The latter deduces the (still fixed at compile time) array size from the number of items between the braces, so you don't have to change a number if in the future you add another array element. But it is still a true array with two elements and not a pointer like `int **m` is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Arrays are not pointers. Pointers are not arrays. And therefore pointer-to-pointers are not arrays of arrays either.

Arrays may in some circumstances "decay" into pointers to their first element, but that doesn't make them pointers.

Correct code in your case is:

```
int x[]={1,2,3,4};
int y[]={5,6,7};

int xy[4][3];
memcpy(xy, x, 4*sizeof x);
memcpy(xy, y, 3*sizeof y);
```

Or alternatively allocate the 2D array dynamically:

```
int (*xy)[3] = malloc( sizeof(int[4][3]) );
```

---

If it makes sense, you could create a pointer-based look-up table using pointers:

```
int* table [2] = {x, y};
```

But this will likely have slower access time than a 2D array.

Answer (score 4):

```
int **m={k,l};
```

is wrong. This is assigning the value of `k` (`int*`) to the variable `m` (`int**`) and leaving the excess element `l` in the initializer unused.

You can use an array

```
int *m[]={k,l};
```

or a compound literal

```
int **m=(int*[]){k,l};
```

instead.